# Getting null value in response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to get the response from https://www.reddit.com/r/popular/.rss and map to Kotlin POJO class in Android. But when I am logging that category's label value, getting null. For the title I am getting response value as popular links.

Here is entity class FeedX:-

```
@Root(name = "feed", strict = false)
class FeedX {
    @set: Element(name = "category")
    @get: Element(name = "category")
    var category: Category? = null
    val entry: List<Entry>? = null
    val id: String? = null
    val link: List<LinkX>? = null
    @set: Element(name = "title")
    @get: Element(name = "title")
    var title: String? = null
    val updated: String? = null

}
```

Category class:-

```
@Root(name = "category", strict = false)
class Category {
    @set: Element(required = false, name = "_label")
    @get: Element(required = false, name = "_label")
    var _label: String? = null
    val _term: String? = null
}
```

Here is Api Interface:-

```
interface FeedApi {

    @GET("{type}/.rss")
    fun getPopularFeeds(
        @Path("type") type: String?
    ): Call<FeedX>?

}
```

Here is MainActivity:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val BASE_URL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(FeedApi::class.java)

        service.getPopularFeeds("popular")?.enqueue(object : Callback<FeedX> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<FeedX>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Response Failed", "${t.localizedMessage}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<FeedX>, response: Response<FeedX>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("Response Success", "${response.body()!!.title}") // for this I am getting value
                    Log.d("Response Success", "${response.body()!!.category?._label}")  // always getting null value
                } else {
                    Log.d("Response Failed jg", "${response.errorBody()}")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I just checked the Json response of Reddit Json API and it has catergory as null. But, I didn't get one thing, if you're using Kotlin, then why are you not using the Json reponse of Reddit?

Comment: You can easily access it as `https://www.reddit.com/top.json?limit=10` [open](https://www.reddit.com/top.json?limit=10), you can change this limit as well. Here's one very detailed series of articles to create [Keddit](https://android.jlelse.eu/keddit-part-6-api-retrofit-kotlin-d309074af0) (Reddit using Kotlin), I read it about two months ago and it can be very useful.

Comment: And if this is what category's label is `label="r/popular"`, then it is provided in the json with the field name `subreddit_name_prefixed` as `"subreddit_name_prefixed": "r/pics"`. Check this [image](https://imgur.com/a/h9sCyE1) and this [Json response](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.479f614445e34234aa9c87fa290c1080).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `title` contains a value where `category` tag doesn't. See the difference below.

```
<title>popular links</title>
```

```
<category term="AskReddit" label="r/AskReddit"/>
```

As you can see `category` tag is self closing.